# Customizing CSS material tab on a table does not work

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular5

In my angular 5 application, I am using Material API.

I have a table with 2 tabs like that:

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab>
    <mat-table>
     <!-- some stuff -->
    </mat-table>
  </mat-tab>
    <mat-table>
     <!-- some stuff -->
    </mat-table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I try to customize the css of `<mat-tab>` component but it is not working, I tried all of that one by one :

```
.mat-tab-label-active {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    background-color: red !important;
  }

  .mat-tab-nav-bar {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    background-color: red !important;
  }

  .mat-tab-group {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    background-color: rgba(19, 23, 63, 0.993) !important;
 }
```

only `.mat-tab-group` is working. I would like to customize only the tab cell and not the whole tab-group. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you put this css in the css file of a component? To make it work, put it on your global css file.

Comment: You don't style post-build components into pre-build files. Either give your table and your lines/colmuns a class (good practice), or put it in your global `style.scss` file (bad practice).

Comment: @Powkachu Yes in the css file of the component. I'll try in the global one

Comment: @trichetriche so the good way to do things, would be to give a class to my <mat-tab> and apply css on it ?

Comment: `mat-table` since you want to customize the table. Also on the components *inside* this table.

Comment: @trichetriche In my project, your good practice does not work. So I put a class and put the corresponding CSS in a global file

Comment: @Powkachu it works, the issue is with your code, not the solution. Putting it in the global css file overrides **all tables**, not only the one you want.

Comment: @trichetriche I already did some CSS on my table and it worked fine. Here I am trying to customize the tab above the table. Sorry if it was not clear in my question I'll edit it.

Comment: @LoganWlv it was indeed not clear ! so yes, put a class into your tab, and edit it on your component.

Comment: @LoganWlv you should also [take a look at the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTab), which explains how you can provide colors, or a custom template, to the tabs.

Comment: @trichetriche I already saw it, but being new to css I do not find it really intuitive.. I tried naming my mat-tab class="myTab" and apply some CSS to it and it didnt work.

Comment: I find it difficult to find which css parameter to call to customize it in the material documentation, could you provide an example for the <mat-tab> component ?@trichetriche

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments : use the `ng-template` property of the mat tabs to customize them. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-obmram?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <ng-template mat-tab-label>
      <span class="customized-label">
        This is a customized label
      </span>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"> Content 3 </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```css
.customized-label {
  color: red;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```